# PreventDefault when calling a named function on a dynamic button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've got this code:

```
$('#my_tecnic').live('click', '#clear_tecnic_form', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    form = document.forms['my_tecnic'];
    form.my_tecnic_nom.value = '';
    form.my_tecnic_nif.value = '';
    form.my_tecnic_regis.value = '';
});
```

I would like to capture the event and call a name function like that:

```
$('#my_tecnic').live('click', '#clear_tecnic_form', clear_tecnic(e));
```

And then do the `preventDefault` like this:

```
function clear_tecnic(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ....
}
```

This isn't working, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass function reference, not invoke function immediately:

```
$('#my_tecnic').live('click', '#clear_tecnic_form', clear_tecnic);
```

Also consider moving to newer jQuery methods, like `on` instead of `.live`.

Comment: I can't update it, I would like to do it, it's 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
$('#my_tecnic').on('click', '#clear_tecnic_form', function(e) { clear_tecnic(e) } );
```

Comment: This is the same I have in my code, that's the way I have make it work